# How can I manage services on a remote computer with the Services MMC snap-in in Windows 8.1 in a workgroup

Tags: windows-service, windows-8.1, workgroup, rpc

I'm trying to manage services of a remote computer in a workgroup via the Services MMC snap-in. Both computers are running Windows 8.1 Pro and are in a private (private as in Windows) network. RDP works between them, but is sometimes unreliable and I don't have physical access to the machine to restart it.

I started with "Error 5: Access Denied". To allow access I have allowed Remote Service Management for private networks in firewall settings, as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/server_core/archive/2008/01/14/configuring-the-firewall-for-remote-management-of-a-workgroup-server-core-installation.aspx). I have also set the LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to 1 as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016/en-us).

While I can run now `sc \\computer stop TermService`, I would like to use the Management Console to do it. But when I try to connect the Services snap-in to the remote machine I'm getting Error 1726: Remote Procedure Call failed.

Any hints what else has to be done to enable remote service administration?

Comment: Remote registry service is probably the missing component here.  Start it and make sure it's allowed through the firewall.

Comment: I have enabled and started the Remote registry service and disabled the Windows firewall, but it still fails with "Remote Procedure Call failed".

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific answer, the steps I would take to troubleshoot it would be do create an any/any exception for your host in the Private profile of the Windows firewall of the host you're trying to manage, just to determine whether or not it's a firewall issue or whether there's something else at play. If it works when you do that, you can use Message Analyser to determine which ports you're accessing on the remote host (I suspect at the very least you'll need to allow 135 for RPC). You can then remove the exception for your management host and create an appropriate firewall rule.

I suspect that will resolve your issue, if not then it's not the firewall causing the problem but something else, but I doubt it will come to that.

Comment: I have disabled the Windows firewall for private networks and it's still the same - "Remote Procedure Call failed".

Answer (score -1):

The thing now works. A restart was needed to make it work.